# markdown source code callouts like asciidoctor?

Tags: markdown, asciidoc, callouts, asciidoctor

I really like the callouts from asciidoctor, see http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/, and search in page "Code block with callouts", click "view result". But I use Ipython notebook for writing, and Markdown is the choice. (Tried Asciidoctor in the Ipython Notebook through the "Raw NBconvert' with messy result.) It seems I only need the source code callouts from Asciidoctor anyway. So my questions is how to achieve similar result from Markdown?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Markdown does not support callouts. There might be a flavour but I am not aware of any and it seems that Ipython Notebook does not use it.

So if you need a workaround, the best solution I could imagine is to add this feature in Javascript - search for the not rendered callouts and replace them on the client.